# How can I use the filter function to increase sample homogeniety?

Tags: r, filter, data-wrangling

I'm looking for a bit of data wrangling advice. My dataset contains two groups of investors (signatory =0, signatory =1). The all have corresponding countries, but the countries of the two groups do not match up.

For my next analysis I need to reduce my dataset down to only the countries present in both groups, so each group will have at least one unit (investor) in the countries listed.

To be really clear, if one group has investors in 45 countries and the other has investors in 50 countries, but only 30 of these countries match up, I want to preserve only those 30 matching countries in the new dataframe.

My data looks like this:

| investor | year | activity | country | region | strategy | signatory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 IM | 2002 | 4.45 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 123 IM | 2003 | 3.2 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 123 IM | 2004 | 7.8 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 21Invest | 2002 | 4.45 | France | europe | VC | 0 |
| 21Invest | 2003 | 3.2 | France | europe | VC | 0 |
| 21Invest | 2004 | 7.8 | France | europe | VC | 0 |
| Aegon | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 1 |
| Aegon | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 1 |
| Aegon | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 1 |
| ING | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| ING | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| ING | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| aberdeen | 2002 | 4.45 | UK | europe | VC | 1 |
| aberdeen | 2003 | 3.2 | UK | europe | VC | 1 |
| aberdeen | 2004 | 7.8 | UK | europe | VC | 1 |
| JPM | 2005 | 5.4 | USA | europe | BY | 0 |
| JPM | 2006 | 4.2 | USA | europe | BY | 0 |
| JPM | 2007 | 1.3 | USA | europe | BY | 0 |

The output I'm looking for is:

| investor | year | activity | country | region | strategy | signatory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 IM | 2002 | 4.45 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 123 IM | 2003 | 3.2 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 123 IM | 2004 | 7.8 | France | europe | VC | 1 |
| 21Invest | 2002 | 4.45 | France | europe | VC | 0 |
| 21Invest | 2003 | 3.2 | France | europe | VC | 0 |
| 21Invest | 2004 | 7.8 | France | europe | VC | 0 |
| Aegon | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 1 |
| Aegon | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 1 |
| Aegon | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 1 |
| ING | 2005 | 5.4 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| ING | 2006 | 4.2 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |
| ING | 2007 | 1.3 | Netherlands | europe | BY | 0 |

Note: the firms from the UK and USA have been dropped, whereas the firms from France and the Netherlands have been retained.

This is because both investor samples (signatory = 0 & signatory = 1) have units in France/NL countries, whereas the UK and USA only feature in one of these samples.

```
df <- data.frame(
investor=c("123 IM", "123 IM", "123 IM", "21Invest", "21Invest", "21Invest", "Aegon", "Aegon", "Aegon", "ING", "ING", "ING", "aberdeen", "aberdeen", "aberdeen", "JPM", "JPM", "JPM"), year=c(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007),
activity=c(4.45, 3.2, 7.8, 5.4, 4.2, 1.3, 4.45, 3.2, 7.8, 5.4, 4.2, 1.3, 4.45, 3.2, 7.8, 5.4, 4.2, 1.3),
country=c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "UK", "UK", "UK", "USA", "USA", "USA"),
region=c("europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "north america", "north america", "north america"),
strategy =c("VC", "VC", "VC", "BY", "BY", "BY", "VC", "VC", "VC", "BY", "BY", "BY", "VC", "VC", "VC", "BY", "BY", "BY"),
signatory =c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

```
df <- data.frame(
investor=c("123 IM", "123 IM", "123 IM", "21Invest", "21Invest", "21Invest", "Aegon", "Aegon", "Aegon", "ING", "ING", "ING", "aberdeen"), year=c(2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007),
activity=c(4.45, 3.2, 7.8, 5.4, 4.2, 1.3, 4.45, 3.2, 7.8, 5.4, 4.2, 1.3),
country=c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands", "Netherlands"),
region=c("europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe", "europe"),
strategy =c("VC", "VC", "VC", "BY", "BY", "BY", "VC", "VC", "VC", "BY", "BY", "BY"),
signatory =c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Rory

Comment: Your example data frame would suggest you end up with no rows because all signatories are in France and all non-signatories are in the Netherlands. There is no overlap at all. Can you provide a better dataset?

Comment: Hi, was just amending as you commented!

Comment: yes, saw it. Amended my answer as well.

Comment: If my answer below answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the v-sign next to it. You can do the same with other questions you have previously asked that have been answered. If you found any of them helpful, you can also upvote them.

Comment: Hi coffieinjunky, thanks for the help so far, it's improved the data but doesn't seem to have quite worked perfectly - I still have 3 countries present in the dataset with only 1 investor. Any idea how that could have happened?

Comment: ah, wait, I think there was a typo. Remove the `!` in `!df$signatory==0` and test again.

Comment: Yes just tested it now, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could do it:

```
library(tidyverse)

signatory_countries <- unique(df[df$signatory==1, 'country'])
non_signatory_countries <- unique(df[df$signatory==0, 'country'])

new_df <- bind_rows(
  df %>% filter(signatory==1, country %in% non_signatory_countries),
  df %>% filter(signatory==0, country %in% signatory_countries)
)
new_df
   investor year activity     country region strategy signatory
1    123 IM 2002     4.45      France europe       VC         1
2    123 IM 2003     3.20      France europe       VC         1
3    123 IM 2004     7.80      France europe       VC         1
4     Aegon 2002     4.45 Netherlands europe       VC         1
5     Aegon 2003     3.20 Netherlands europe       VC         1
6     Aegon 2004     7.80 Netherlands europe       VC         1
7  21Invest 2005     5.40      France europe       BY         0
8  21Invest 2006     4.20      France europe       BY         0
9  21Invest 2007     1.30      France europe       BY         0
10      ING 2005     5.40 Netherlands europe       BY         0
11      ING 2006     4.20 Netherlands europe       BY         0
12      ING 2007     1.30 Netherlands europe       BY         0
```